# How to add rxjs pipe operator dynamically with condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, pipeline, angular-akita

I'm trying to insert 2 pipe operators into pipe function, but I want to apply the first one by condition, else, only the second one will be applied.

that's the way it looks now without the condition:

`getData(query).pipe(setLoding(this.store),tap(//some actions here...))`

**setLoading** is an Akita pipe, and I would like it to be applied with some boolean condition.

I tried to use rxjs's `iif()` but I received an error since `setLoding` is not a type of `SubscribableOrPromise`.

Can anyone think of another way?

Answer (score 1):

Using the rxjs `iif`, you can conditionally write observables but it is not used for dealing with operators.

Since the `setLoading` is an operator in your case, it can not be used with `iif`. To use `setLoading` conditionally in pipe, you'll have to write something similar to -

```
getData(query)
.pipe(
  condition ? setLoading(this.store): tap(() => /* some other action */ )
)
```

**EDIT:**

In case you don't want to do anything in the else case and execute the `tap` always, you need to use the `identity` operator.

```
getData(query)
.pipe(
  condition ? setLoading(this.store): identity,
  tap(() => /* some other action */ )
)
```

Comment: this way forces me to add an "else" statement. I have an error of ": expected".
Is there is any way to do nothing in the "else" case and still moving on to tap operator?

Comment: @Iris Yes, using the `identity` operator. Updated the answer.